# Does Http get of Angular2 only support Json?

Tags: json, rest, http, angular

**ufc-api.service.ts**

```
getFighters() {
    return this.http.get('http://ufc-data-api.ufc.com/api/v3/fighters')
                    .map(res => res.json());
}
```

**fighter.component.ts**

```
data: string;

constructor(private ufcApiService: UfcApiService) { }

clickGetFighter() {
  this.ufcApiService.getFighters()
  .subscribe(result => {
    this.data = JSON.stringify(result);
  },
  error => {
    this.data = error;
  },
  () => console.log('fighters done!!'));
}
```

It is not working and I get the error below:

> { "_body": {}, "status": 0, "ok": false, "statusText": "", "headers": {}, "type": 3, "url": null }

It is working if I made restful api myself but this is from website of UFC data API.

Is there any way to get html string using http get on angular2 such as HttpClient on .net ?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide headers to your application.
In your case it will be text/plain.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need to do `res.text()` instead of `res.json()`